# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow' erro windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to install Keras with Tensorflow. I have followed all steps from

[here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows)

I have installed CUDA 9 . cuDNN 7.i had problems intalling it with command provided on the site so i used

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

which i have found here on SO. Installation went fine, however when i tried test script ( provided on the tensorflow site ) i recieved error:

> No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow

I have tried to check SO for answer but found nothing usefull, how can fix this?

thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your issues you are installing cpu only and old MAC version of tensorflow which shouldn't work on windows.
You could try using the following command

```
python3 -m pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-0.12.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

But I suggest you use Anaconda for the windows to install tensorflow and keras it has much less errors on windows, you can find a guide for it here https://github.com/antoniosehk/keras-tensorflow-windows-installation.

Comment: Thanks, i will try installing with Anaconda, however ur command gives me error about tf not being supported on platform..

Comment: @Darlyn Are you on 64-bit windows or 32? Also can you check your python version this one is for python 3.5

Comment: I am running windows 10 64 bit.  i am running python 3.6, where does it say anything about python version?

Comment: You could use this wheel for `python3 -m pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.6.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl` it is in the url `cp3x-cp3xm`

Comment: where do you look this links up? + i get same error